# LINQ Recursive query in web api code

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api2

Need to write a recursive query via `LINQ` in my `Web Api` Code.
The table structure is as follows:

```
create table dbo.Test(
ID int primary key not null,
Name nvarchar(20) not null,
[Description] nvarchar(20) not null,
Parent_ID int)

ID      Name            Description     Parent_ID
1001    BusinessUnit    BU              NULL
1002    BrandUnit       Brand           1001
1003    Branch1         LondonBranch1   1002
1004    Branch2         LondonBranch2   1002
1005    Branch3         LondonBranch3   1002
```

My Web API Code is as follows:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
    public class TestDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }
    public TestDTO Get()
    {
        using (var db = new SampleEntities())
        {
            var hardcodedBusinessUnitID=1001;
            var xx = db.Tests.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(hardcodedBusinessUnitID)).ID;
            List<int> list=new List<int>();
            list.Add(xx);
            var idFromUI=1009;

            return new TestDTO
            {
                Name = list.Contains(idFromUI) ? "Match Found" : string.Empty,
                Desc = "Blah Blah"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I somehow need to get all the children of the `ID` 1001(as 1001 has one child with id 1002, which further has 3 children with ids 1003,1004 and 1005) from the database via a `LINQ` query and bind them in a `list`.

Post that I'll get an `ID` from `UI` and will check whether the `ID` from `UI` exists in that list or not.

I am not able to do it, because I am not very well versed in `LINQ`.

Experts please help.

Comment: Doing recursion in LINQ seems like a bad idea in this case. You will need to call the database multiple times, and an additional time for every branch in your hierarchy. It probably makes more sense to do in a stored procedure.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst I too have the same concern, but to my bad I don't have the liberty to add a stored procedure. Any other idea?

Comment: This appears to be a multi-level menu. If you have linq build this into some sort of data object or just return the whole list would be the same. You still have to either loop inside of a loop to build out the menu or call a method recursively but either way you want to do this client side and not in the API.

Comment: @StephenBrickner How should I return the whole list as per the ID provided? What sorta LINQ should I write? Any pointers?

Comment: Is there ever a time you would start part way down and not take them all? If that's the case then pass in an ID and var items = context.Test.Where(x => x.ID == ID || x.Parent_ID == ID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a temporary list of items that you use to find children; you empty the list and put the children in that list and repeat. Probably something like this:

```
var parent = db.Tests.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID.Equals(hardcodedBusinessUnitID)).ID;

// a list of the type of your object, to store all the items
var items = new List<Test>();
items.Add(parent)

// make a new list that will be used to search the table
searchItems = new List<Test>(items);
while (searchItems.Any())
{
    var ids = searchItems.Select(i => i.ID).ToList();
    searchItems = db.Tests.Where(t => 
        t.Parent_ID.HasValue && ids.Contains(t.Parent_ID.Value)).ToList();
    items.AddRange(searchItems);
}

List<int> list = items.Select(i => i.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Let me try to implement.

Comment: GIves a compiler error on the line searchItems = db.Tests.Where(t => ids.Contains(t.Parent_ID)).ToList(); because Parent_ID column is a nullable one.

Comment: I changed this code to handle the nullable `Parent_ID`.

Comment: @Kirk..Amazing solution.Thanks for it. Where do i study LINQ from? I am pretty poor at it.

Comment: Practice, and check out http://www.linqpad.net/masteringlinq.aspx or https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0):

You might think about it differently. Start your search with the id you look for from the UI and go up in the hierarchy until you find a test record with no parent. Then compare that test record with no parent ID against your hard coded ID. If they match, then the id from UI is a child; otherwise not.

```
var t = db.Tests.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == idFromUI);
if(t != null){
    int? parentId = t.Parent_ID;
    int rootParentId = -1;
    while(parentId != null){
        var currentTest = db.Tests.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == parentId);
        if(currentTest != null){
            parentId = currentTest.Parent_ID;
            rootParentId = currentTest.ID;
        }
        else{
           parentId = null;
        }
    }
    if(rootParentId == hardcodedBusinessUnitID){
        return new TestDTO
        {
            Name = "Match Found",
            Desc = "Blah Blah"
        };
    }        
}

return new TestDTO
        {
            Name = string.Empty,
            Desc = "Blah Blah"
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: @Anurag So did you try?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. the above answer sufficed for me, but for sure I'm gonna try your approach and will let ya know. Thanks

Comment: In my approach, you don't need to find all children. I think my way is more efficient, but it's your call.